# After installing opencv on ubuntu 16.04 i get error no module opencv

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, opencv3.0

When i use `import cv2` i got error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cv2'`. But i am sure that i have installed opencv properly. and used many times. I update anaconda and spyder after that ia ma getting this problem. I am using python `3.6.5` on anaconda. When i type `pkg-config opencv --cflags` i get  `-I/usr/local/include/opencv -I/usr/local/include` for confirming open cv is installed. and when i type `pkg-config --modversion opencv` i get `3.3.0` (version). For more information when i type `pkg-config opencv --libs` i get

```
-L/usr/local/lib -lopencv_cudabgsegm -lopencv_cudaobjdetect -lopencv_cudastereo -lopencv_dnn -lopencv_ml -lopencv_shape -lopencv_stitching -lopencv_cudafeatures2d -lopencv_superres -lopencv_cudacodec -lopencv_videostab -lopencv_cudaoptflow -lopencv_cudalegacy -lopencv_calib3d -lopencv_features2d -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_videoio -lopencv_photo -lopencv_imgcodecs -lopencv_cudawarping -lopencv_cudaimgproc -lopencv_cudafilters -lopencv_video -lopencv_objdetect -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_flann -lopencv_cudaarithm -lopencv_core -lopencv_cudev
```

How to solve problem

Comment: pkg-config returns compilation and linker flags for c(++) libraries not python modules.

Comment: how did you install opencv?

Comment: On ubuntu you can install opencv for python with `sudo apt install python-opencv` or sometimes pip instal opencv. These methods use the Ubuntu-16.04 or pip repositories. I do not know how they operate if you use anaconda python.

Comment: @FlyingTeller i forgot how i install opencv. May be using conda

Comment: Hard to help if you forgot about that... How about install it again using `conda install opencv` and make sure you are using anaconda's python?

Comment: @hkchengrex ok. Will `conda install opencv` automatically remove previously install opencv

Comment: No, but it will tell you that you already have one installed (if the previous one is installed by conda).

Comment: @hkchengrex `sudo find / -name "*opencv*" -exec rm -rf {} \;` is this command will remove previous opencv

Comment: Previous installation probably wouldn't mess you up if you use anaconda. I would leave it as is if I were you.

Comment: @hkchengrex works for me

Comment: Ok I will make it as an answer for future reference.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible that you are using a different anaconda, or opencv got uninstalled when you updated anaconda. You can install opencv for anaconda's python again using `conda install opencv`.

After installation, also make sure that you are using anaconda's python instead of the system's python. When you run `python` in console, `Anaconda` should be displayed.